Does androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity work in Android Studio Jellyfish | 2023.3.1?
I am using the latest Android studio build (of 2023.3.1.) I'm trying to include the following package:
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity


I get the following error: (referring to line 3 of MainActivity.kt)
Unresolved reference: app: 3


Why can't this package be found? What has this package been superseded by?

Well how are you adding the dependency for that class? Also, is that the whole error? "app: 3" makes little sense ...

Ok, found the solution eventually. In build.gradle.kts, add this to dependencies:
`dependencies {
val appcompat_version = "1.6.1"

implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$appcompat_version")

`
[See: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/appcompat#kts]
I also did: 'clean project' and 'rebuild project'.
